# what's the python code to transpose panel data to make it easier for regression and further analysis

Tags: python, dataframe, regression, transpose, panel-data

[image: my current data]

I would like to have the data transposed into this format:

[image: needed data format]

I have done this before in STATA and I am currently trying to re-do my previous work in python to ensure I learn it effectively.

Comment: check out [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) - this isn't a transpose so that could be why you're having trouble finding related questions/examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you have a multi-header DataFrame, try with `stack`:

```
>>> df.set_index(("RIC", "Year")).stack().rename_axis(["RIC", "Year"]).reset_index()
        RIC  Year            MV
0     AFL.N  2015   28403890000
1     AFL.N  2016   34511000000
2     AFL.N  2017   34684000000
3     AFL.N  2018   38830000000
4     AES.N  2015    7659620000
5     AES.N  2016    7151980000
6     AES.N  2017    9576820000
7     AES.N  2018   13213000000
8     ABT.N  2015   56551380000
9     ABT.N  2016   99330000000
10    ABT.N  2017  127000000000
11    ABT.N  2018  154000000000
12  ABMD.OQ  2015    4888170000
13  ABMD.OQ  2016    8286540000
14  ABMD.OQ  2017   14646000000
15  ABMD.OQ  2018    7695790000
```